# jQuery.min.js not loading correctly after moving WordPress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

After moving my WordPress site to a new location, I started seeing weird behavior in the WP admin, including:

1. When clicking into a post for editing, a message in red saying "The block editor requires JavaScript. Please enable JavaScript in your browser settings or try the Classic Editor plugin" briefly pops up and then the page goes completely white.
2. In my theme options (Divi Extra), the options are all listed but their Enable/Disable toggle buttons are gone.
3. On certain plugins' settings screens, things like dragging and dropping and clicking on tabs to view additional settings have stopped working.

When checking the browser console after experiencing these things, I'm seeing a lot of "jQuery.Deferred exception: jQuery (someFunction) is not a function" and corresponding "Uncaught TypeError: jQuery (someFunction) is not a function" for several jQuery functions. For example:

```
jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: jQuery(...).sortable is not a function TypeError: jQuery(...).sortable is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:1:69)
    at e (https://example.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1:2:30005)
    at t (https://example.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1:2:30307) undefined
    
Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).sortable is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:1:69)
    at e (jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1:2)
    at t (jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1:2)
```

The reading I've been doing on this makes it sound like the problem is that jQuery functions are being asked to run before they've been defined, and that the solution is to make sure jQuery gets loaded before anything dependant on it does. That makes sense but when I check the source code, this is right near the top of the page:

```
<script src='https://example.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1' id='jquery-core-js' type="text/psajs" orig_index="2"></script>
```

I haven't done anything with wp_enqueue_script () because everything I've read so far makes it seem like that only comes into play if I'm adding some custom js...but the only "custom" javascript on my site is whatever's included with the plugins I've got. And again, none of this was happening before I moved WordPress.

What I'm trying to understand specifically is:

1. Is my problem that jquery.min.js is not loading fast/soon enough on these admin pages?
2. If so, what is the best way to force it to load faster/sooner?

Thanks in advance for anyone able and willing to provide assistance!

Comment: Check if there isn't another jQuery.js version being loaded further down the page that would wipe out plugins assigned to the first version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning off a module on my web server called mod_pagespeed_beacon fixed all three of these issues.